# How to get data stored in child node generated by autoid?

Tags: swift, firebase

Whats the best way to get data that is stored under a child node that is generated by autoid  in swift.

structure of firebase Database

```
 book007
    +---isbn                          //1st node
    +---user                          //2nd node
    +---userBooks                     //3rd node
        | --TikubNudhfiI90uNKIij        //3rd childnode  
        |    +-Thuimfim9876HUIhinn .   //3rd  childnode AutoGeneratedID
        |       --ThufdsfsYI7ihhuhGGU
        |            --BookIsbn:"23432423"     //need to get this node   
        |    +-ThuisddfsdUUHKIhinn
```

The code is not optimized i believe as there should be a better way to do it.

```
   func fetchuser(){

        print("Fetching UserBooks!!")
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            print("No UID on fetchBook!!")
            return
        }

        Database.database().reference().child("userBooks").child(uid).observe(.childAdded, with: { (ChildKeysnapshot) in
            let partkey = ChildKeysnapshot.key
            print("partkey",partkey)

            // user > keys > all books (godeep = isbneach book)
         Database.database().reference().child("userBooks").child(uid).child(partkey).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (isbnShot) in

                if let DictIsbn = isbnShot.value as?[String:AnyObject]{

                    let isbnCell = BkCells()
                    isbnCell.setValuesForKeys(DictIsbn)
                    print("New updateISBN OF THIS USER",  isbnCell.bookISBN)
                    self.users.append(isbnCell)
                    print("IsbncellIS this",self.users.count)
                }

            print("This is Ron Before")
            self.fetchUserIsbn()

         }, withCancel: nil)

        }, withCancel: nil)
   }
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. When you say  'get data' what do you mean? In this case, the userBook node is being observed by .childAdded. That will present any newly added child nodes *and all of their child data* to the app. As your code stands if node *Thuimfim9876HUIhinn* was just added, it, and all of the children like *ThufdsfsYI7ihhuhGGU* with it's child *BookIsbn* will be in the snapshot. If there are multiple child nodes and you are asking how to work with those, you can iterate over them as their own snapshots. Perhaps clarifying the question a bit would lead to a better answer.

Comment: Will there be multiple child nodes within /userBooks / +-TikubNudhfiI90uNKIij / --Thuimfim9876HUIhinn.. as it is, it's showing one, which is ThufdsfsYI7ihhuhGGU (which contains /BookIsbn)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are observing a user's books with the `childAdded` event which will trigger for each child under the user's books node. The snapshot returned inside the closure is for each book and so there is no need to request the books value again.

```
func fetchuser(){

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "userBooks/\(uid)")

    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        if let bookIsbn = snapshot.child("BookIsbn").value as? String {
            print(bookIsbn)
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

You should make a change to the `BkCells` model so one can be initialized via a `DataSnapshot`.

```
import Firebase

class BkCells: NSObject {

    var bookIsbn: String!

    init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

        guard
            let bookIsbn = snapshot.child("BookIsbn").value as? String
        else { 
            return nil
        }

        self.bookIsbn = bookIsbn
    }
}
```

You can create a `BkCell` instance for each book snapshot under a user's `userBooks` node.

```
ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
    if let bkCells = BkCells(snapshot: snapshot) {
        print(bkCells.bookIsbn)
    }
}, withCancel: nil)
```

Comment: understood that, but didn't get it to get the value of the Bookisbn? as mentioned int the figure and question